# I have been building an app in react-native, but libraries disappear

Tags: ios, react-native

I have been building an app in react-native, it contains several components: Firebase, Navigation, Facebook and Google Login, Camera, Push Notificatins, as well as others. When I try to build the app in IOS, libraries that I have previously installed are no longer there, it's like they just disappeared. I know there is a reason, can anyone explain the details of what is happening so that I can move forward and prevent this in the future?

Comment: Have you linked all your libraries properly??

Comment: yes, I believe so. I have either pulled them into xCode or used react-native link or put them into my Pod file, depending on what the directions were.